# Modified text entry for answering quiz questions. How to move text from an array of buttons to an array of textviews one letter at a time?

Tags: android, kotlin

Retired English professor trying his hand at Kotlin/Android.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

In a quiz app, the user gets a clue to solve; s/he is presented with a grid of buttons the text of each of which is a single letter drawn from a shuffled list that contains all the letters needed for the correct answer, plus a few random extra letters.  Pressing a button transfers the corresponding letter to the first empty textview of an answer grid.  Pressing another button enters its letter into the next text view, and so on.

So far I can get the first letter chosen into the first text view, but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to ensure that the next button pressed results in its text  being transferred to the next available text view.  Have spent days poking around Kotlin/Java sites looking for examples, but no luck.

Not asking for anyone to write my code for me, just for a suggestion as to how best to think about the next steps, the logic of which is eluding me.  Examples welcome, of course.  Chiding admonitions, not so much.

Here's the .kt attempt to this point:

```
 package com.example.letterbuttons


import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.letterbuttons.databinding.ActivityMainBinding


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    var titleString = ("HERZOGMELSOCNA")


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val a = binding.button1
        val b = binding.button2
        val c = binding.button3
        val d = binding.button4
        val e = binding.button5
        val f = binding.button6
        val g = binding.button7
        val h = binding.button8
        val i = binding.button9
        val j = binding.button10
        val k = binding.button11
        val m = binding.button12
        val n = binding.button13
        val o = binding.button14


        val letterChoices = arrayOf(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, m, n, o)
        titleString = titleString
            .toList()
            .shuffled()
            .joinToString(separator = "")


        for ((index, element) in titleString.withIndex()) {
            letterChoices[index].text = ("$element")
        }
        listOf(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, m, n, o).forEach {
            it.setOnClickListener(::click)
        }


    }


    fun click(view: View) {
        with(view as Button) {
            val tv1 = binding.textView1
            val tv2 = binding.textView2
            val tv3 = binding.textView3
            val tv4 = binding.textView4
            val tv5 = binding.textView5
            val tv6 = binding.textView6
            val tv7 = binding.textView7
            val tv8 = binding.textView8
            val tv9 = binding.textView9
            val tv10 = binding.textView10
            val tv11 = binding.textView11
            val tv12 = binding.textView12
            val tv13 = binding.textView13
            val tv14 = binding.textView14
            val tv15 = binding.textView15
            val tv16 = binding.textView16
            val tv17 = binding.textView17
            val tv18 = binding.textView18
            val answerChoices = arrayOf(
                tv1,
                tv2,
                tv3,
                tv4,
                tv5,
                tv6,
                tv7,
                tv8,
                tv9,
                tv10,
                tv11,
                tv12,
                tv13,
                tv14,
                tv15,
                tv16,
                tv17,
                tv18
            )


            for ((i, element) in answerChoices.withIndex()) {


            var text = view.text
            var tv = answerChoices[0]
            tv.text = text


//then what? (clearly not this):
         //   var nextTv = answerChoices[+1]
         //   nextTv.requestFocus()
         //   nextTv.text = text

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have an array of all the buttons and textViews. All you have to do is instead of this

```
listOf(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, m, n, o).forEach {
            it.setOnClickListener(::click)
        }
```

you can use the array of buttons here and map the indices with the textviews.

```
for ((i, element) in letterChoices.withIndex()) {
    element.onClickListener(){
        answerChoices[i].text = element.text
    }
}
```

PS: This is just a pseudo code.